# Why is wp_head wrecking havoc on my CSS?

Tags: css, html, wordpress

My problem is that when I comment out `wp_head` in my `header.php`, the CSS looks fine. But I'm currently using plugins (Mailpoet, Formidable) for the website. When `wp_head` is commented out, the AJAX for the aforementioned plugins won't work. If `wp_head` is added, unnecessary margins pop out, and font-sizes and line-heights become mess. I'm going at it for one and a half day now. Any help would be appreciated. And yes, I put `wp_footer` in `footer.php`. I use HTML5 blank as my theme and my current WordPress version is 4.2.4. If you need any clarifications please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

Comment: ^what css should i remove good sir?

Comment: Whichever files you were trying to remove by commenting out `wp_head`.

Comment: ^only header.php contains my wp_head. i just comment it out or retain it there.thaks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just download the css and js that the plugin/s use/s then put it/them in your css or/and js folder.